# Configure Oplog Size in MongoDB Bitnami Replicaset Architecture

Tags: mongodb, bitnami, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-oplog

I cannot find the way to configure a higher MongoDB oplog size in the Bitnami Helm chart for MongoDB, [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb/).

My understanding is that the oplog will keep all the recent data up to a certain size, or age, and then discard it. That oplog allows replicas that went offline to catch up with the primary oplog once they come back online.

However I cannot see the way to configure it, nor I can see the default value that it takes. According to MongoDB documentation, for linux will be 5% of free space, minium of
990MB and maximum of 50GB, but for the Bitnami helm chart this might be different.

I will be saving pictures in the database and they can be around 1MB each after compression. That will fill up an oplog faster than databases using text only.

As a bonus question, is it required for a Hidden Mongo Node to have an oplog the same size as other nodes that could become primary?  I could not find the answer to that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it on the bitnami Helm Chart by using the `extraFlags` parameter. That parameter will pass the options to the MongoDB startup.

Checking the MongoDB docs you can use the `replication.oplogSizeMB`, explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-replication.oplogSizeMB). The reference is for the MongoDB configuration file, but as explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file) the options on the configuration file are equivalent to the command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

Try [rs.printReplicationInfo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.printReplicationInfo/)

The output is like this:

```
configured oplog size:   192MB
log length start to end: 65422secs (18.17hrs)
oplog first event time:  Mon Jun 23 2014 17:47:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)
oplog last event time:   Tue Jun 24 2014 11:57:40 GMT-0400 (EDT)
now:                     Thu Jun 26 2014 14:24:39 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

You see the oplog size. The time at `log length start to end` means, a SECONDARY which was disconnected less than 18.17 hours ago is still able to synchronize.